# Can't give css class to django error message

Tags: python, css, django

I'm trying to format my Django error messages with some css, but i just can't seem to apply it. (The CSS file is added correctly I applied other classes from it, those work just fine). The strange thing about it is that if i try to apply a class from bootstrap like "alert-danger" that works just fine

Here's my html code:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="asd">{{ field.errors}}</div>
{% endfor %}
```

And the css as well

```
.asd{
font-size: 1rem;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Here's the form:

```
class UserRegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
email = forms.EmailField()

class Meta:
    model = User
    fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']
    error_css_class = 'asd'
```

Comment: did you try clearing browser cache or hard reloading ? browser maybe using the cached css file

Comment: Yes I did, even tried multiple browsers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1)first thing is error_css_class must be outside of meta not the inside of meta class

2)and the second thing is in django error always come as a unordered list so do one thing put error_css_class = "error" in proper place on the for and add css like this so it might work for you

```
.error li {
font-size: 1rem;
margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: I made the end tag for the div, and i tried adding the error_css_class but still nothing

Comment: I'll edit my post, so I can show you my form's code aswell

Comment: check the answer